# How does a web request discern geographic location

Tags: networking, routing

I have done quite a bit of reading regarding the internet layers, but have yet to find an answer. Say you are in city x and a server is in city y. Along the miles and miles of wiring, who controls and how do they control which paths the data takes? Furthermore, once it's reached city y, how do they send the data down the right path to the house or specific location of the server.

I had an very similar question regarding cellphones, but if this isn't the right forum for that then please ignore this part of the question and focus on the question above: When a call goes out to phone number xxx-xxxx does number xxx-xxxy hear the request and simply ignore it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does geolocation based on IP address work?](http://superuser.com/questions/445879/how-does-geolocation-based-on-ip-address-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really asking two questions here.  Knowing where you're physically located in the world is different from actually routing traffic to you.  The irony is that a web site does not need to know where you are at all, and knowing where you are doesn't help them route traffic to you.

**Discerning your geographical location:**
In a typical home networking setup, your router has a public IP address assigned to it by your ISP that everyone else in the world can see.  Your ISP has been allocated a block of addresses by some regional authority which differs by country, but is ultimately derived from the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA).

IANA keeps a database of all IP blocks on the Internet, who they have been assigned to, and where they are located.  IANA also maintains a network of servers all over the world that keep lists of all the domain names on the Internet as well.  These databases are public record; anyone on the Internet can look up the information contained in them.

When you make a web request, your public IP address becomes known to that server.  There is no magic or backtracing involved in finding out where you are in the world.  Since IP address blocks are assigned to geographical regions, a web site can simply look you up and know (down to at least the city) where you are physically located.

**How data is routed to you:**
In addition to the public IP address your ISP gave you, your router also has a private IP address which is visible only to the computers on your network.  Your router becomes your *default gateway*.

Let's say you visit Google's web site, which has an address of 173.194.33.112. Your computer does not know how to reach that address, so it sends the request to your default gateway (your router) and trusts that it knows how to get there.

The problem is that your router doesn't know how to get to that address either, so it forwards the request to it's default gateway (which is some router owned by your ISP) trusting that *it* knows how to get to that address.

The ISP's router probably doesn't know how to get to that address either, so it forwards your request to yet another gateway (which may be some other internet provider's router), trusting that IT knows how to get to that address.

This process repeats over and over again as many times as necessary until finally some router on some network somewhere in the world knows how to reach one of Google's routers, which can take it from there.

Each "hop" along the way does not carry any information about the other hops.  The only thing that's necessary to get traffic from point A to point B is the destination address (where you're trying to go), and your computer's source address (so the destination can reply back to you).  That's it.  The reply takes the same multi-hop journey back to you.

This happens with every single packet.  Millions of times a second.  Frankly, it's amazing that it works so well.  No router on the internet has a complete picture of the entire Internet.  It's just not possible; the Internet is too big.

So as you can see, knowing *where* you are, and knowing *how* to contact you are two very different things, and one is not required for the other.

Comment: So let's say the server is in China, could my request potentially end up in Europe, Africa, and south America as each router sends the packet in all directions in search of the router that finally knows where the server is? And once it does contact the server, does the circuitous journey begin all over again since the routers did not store any information about the previous trip?

Comment: Potentially yes, although the path is not so chaotic and random. Each router upstream from you is connected to bigger and bigger networks, which have multiple interfaces. When a packet is received it makes a decision about which path to forward your packet along. So if it has routes to Asia, South America, and Europe, it's not going to route you to a European network if the destination address is in Asia (although the terms "Asia" and "Europe" have no meaning to it. They're just different IP blocks and your destination is within one of them).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that each device has as much information as it needs to figure out which device to pass the information to next. This information is either included in the information it receives or stored locally in that device (often some combination).

For example, my computer has enough information to determine whether a packet should be sent to another computer on my LAN or to my router. That's all it needs. Every packet includes the destination IP address, the computer knows which destination IP addresses part of my LAN, and the computer knows how to forward a packet to my router if it's IP address is outside that range.

Similarly, my router has enough information to know whether data should go to a device on my LAN or to my ISP. That's all it needs. The device my router is connected to has enough information to tell whether traffic should go to one of the customers directly connected to it or not, and that's all it needs.

Eventually, you'll get to "core" routers that figure out which provider the traffic needs to go to and find the route "towards" that provider. These also enforce policy and ensure traffic from A to C only goes through B if B agreed to carry that traffic. The Internet's global routing fabric is maintained by communication between core routers using a protocol called [BGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol).

The answer to your cellphone question depends on the exact technology being used. It may or may not, but in pretty much all schemes, the traffic is encrypted and other devices would not have the key. Generally, a device does receive some subset of the traffic sent to other devices but rarely all of it.